# Multiple linear regression line

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have tried to add linear regression line onto all 4 plots but have not been able to even process it.

```
\addplot table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]{
        (1.0,   0.816286793)
        (1.5,   0.81474159)
        (2.0,   0.77101728)
        (2.5,   0.733906267)
        (3.0,   0.693063823)
        (4.0,   0.660231965)
        (5.0,   0.62408223)
        (6.0,   0.627902353)
};
```

I tried inserting the above code below each plot to generate the linear regression line but always comes up with error?

[image]

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \numberwithin{figure}{section}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \graphicspath{{F}}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{spy}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[x post scale=2, y post scale=1.5,xlabel=Injection Pressure (Bar) ,ylabel=Coefficient Discharge, xmin=0, xmax=7, ymin=0.5, ymax=1]
            \addlegendentry{1/4 Lift}
        \addplot [color=blue,mark=o, smooth] coordinates {
    (1.0,   0.816286793)
    (1.5,   0.81474159)
    (2.0,   0.77101728)
    (2.5,   0.733906267)
    (3.0,   0.693063823)
    (4.0,   0.660231965)
    (5.0,   0.62408223)
    (6.0,   0.627902353)

        };
            \addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
        \addplot [color=red,mark=triangle, smooth] coordinates {
    (1.0,   0.825289956)
    (1.5,   0.808615713)
    (2.0,   0.77101728)
    (2.5,   0.731375556)
    (3.0,   0.662742281)
    (4.0,   0.657230911)
    (5.0,   0.657635038)
    (6.0,   0.661594675)
        };
            \addlegendentry{3/4 Lift}
        \addplot [color=green,mark=10-pointed star, smooth] coordinates {
    (1.0,   0.861302609)
    (1.5,   0.852722025)
    (2.0,   0.81911744)
    (2.5,   0.685822753)
    (3.0,   0.675737228)
    (4.0,   0.681239346)
    (5.0,   0.657635038)
    (6.0,   0.66281985)

        };
            \addlegendentry{Full Lift}
        \addplot [color=yellow,mark=+, smooth] coordinates {
    (1.0,   0.862803136)
    (1.5,   0.863136015)
    (2.0,   0.824776283)
    (2.5,   0.682026686)
    (3.0,   0.679202547)
    (4.0,   0.676737764)
    (5.0,   0.669714049)
    (6.0,   0.669558314)    

        };
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{Cd vs Re for straight nozzle}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a line with column names and to remove the round braces and the comma:

```
\addplot table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}]{
         X      Y
        1.0   0.816286793
        1.5   0.81474159
        2.0   0.77101728
        2.5   0.733906267
        3.0   0.693063823
        4.0   0.660231965
        5.0   0.62408223
        6.0   0.627902353
};
```

Because the `x` coordinates in all plots are equal you can use declare one table containing the values for all plots.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}% loads pgfplots, tikz, graphicx
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}% <- added!

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % one table for all plots
        \pgfplotstableread{
    X     Y1            Y2            Y3            Y4
    1.0   0.816286793   0.825289956   0.861302609   0.862803136
    1.5   0.81474159    0.808615713   0.852722025   0.863136015
    2.0   0.77101728    0.77101728    0.81911744    0.824776283
    2.5   0.733906267   0.731375556   0.685822753   0.682026686
    3.0   0.693063823   0.662742281   0.675737228   0.679202547
    4.0   0.660231965   0.657230911   0.681239346   0.676737764
    5.0   0.62408223    0.657635038   0.657635038   0.669714049
    6.0   0.627902353   0.661594675   0.66281985    0.669558314
        }\data

        \begin{axis}[
          x post scale=2, y post scale=1.5,
          xlabel=Injection Pressure (Bar) ,
          ylabel=Coefficient Discharge,
          xmin=0, xmax=7,
          ymin=0.5, ymax=1,
          regline/.style={dashed,forget plot}
          ]
            \addlegendentry{1/4 Lift}
        \addplot [color=blue,mark=o, smooth] table [y=Y1] {\data};
        \addplot [blue,regline] table [y={create col/linear regression={y=Y1}}] {\data};
            \addlegendentry{1/2 Lift}
        \addplot [color=red,mark=triangle, smooth] table [y=Y2] {\data};
        \addplot [red,regline] table [y={create col/linear regression={y=Y2}}] {\data};
            \addlegendentry{3/4 Lift}
        \addplot [color=green,mark=10-pointed star, smooth] table [y=Y3] {\data};
        \addplot [green,regline] table [y={create col/linear regression={y=Y3}}] {\data};
            \addlegendentry{Full Lift}
        \addplot [color=yellow,mark=+, smooth] table [y=Y4] {\data};
        \addplot [yellow,regline] table [y={create col/linear regression={y=Y4}}] {\data};
        \end{axis}%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{Cd vs Re for straight nozzle}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]